# Pivot by count of values in multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, pivot-table

I have a dataframe where multiple columns have a 0, 1, or 5 as the values. I want to be able to pivot the table so that the columns are 0, 1 and 5, the rows are the original column names and the values are the count of each time a 0, 1, or 5 appeared in the original column.

the original table:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
0    1    0    5
1    1    0    1
1    0    1    1
```

Desired Table:

```
      0   1   5
col1  1   2   0
col2  1   2   0
col3  2   1   0
col4  0   2   1
```

What is the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `Series.value_counts`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).T
```

---

```
      0  1  5
col1  1  2  0
col2  1  2  0
col3  2  1  0
col4  0  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly as needed. Can I ask what the .T is for?

Comment: @RalphDelNegro `.T` is for taking the `transpose` of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

An approach is using [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) , then [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
u = df.melt()
out = pd.crosstab(u['variable'],u['value']).rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
```

---

```
print(out)

      0  1  5
col1  1  2  0
col2  1  2  0
col3  2  1  0
col4  0  2  1
```